# Create SQLite database on sdcard in ionic3

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm tring to use native @ionic-native/sqlite module with ionic3. If I create a SQLite db in the default location the database gets created.

```
  constructor( public sqlite: SQLite) {
    this.initDatabase();

  }


  initDatabase(){

    config = {
      name: 'offline.db',
      location: 'default'
    }
    this.sqlite.create(this.config).then(async  (db: SQLiteObject) => {
      await db.executeSql(`
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cond_pag (
          id_codizione_pag varchar(4),
          descrizione varchar(150),
          CONSTRAINT cond_pag_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_codizione_pag)  
       )`,{});

      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });    

  }


}
```

but if I try to use the sd card insetad

```
config = {
      name: 'offline.db',
      location: '/sdcard'
}
```

ionic throws an error

```
Error: Valid iOS database location could not be determined in openDatabase call
    at newSQLError (SQLitePlugin.js:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (SQLitePlugin.js:581)
    at Object.openDatabase (SQLitePlugin.js:59)
    at index.js:199
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at SQLite.create (index.js:198)
    at SQLite.value [as create] (decorators.js:49)
    at DatabaseProvider.webpackJsonp.200.DatabaseProvider.initDatabase (database.ts:28)
    at new DatabaseProvider (database.ts:20)
    at _createClass (core.js:10933)
```

what's missing?

Comment: First you need permission to write files into sdcard(get permissions using ionic diagnostic plugin), next i think you should specify `iosDatabaseLocation` follow [link](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)

Comment: Thanks NRaghavendra . I tryed to add user permission for Android Platform but I get the same message. I found another way out. I configured ionic to compile into assets directory of a Android studio project. I created an app based on WebView component. Now I can access native function from TypeSpript and Java-Android does the dirty job. My customer wants only the Android version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me

```
initDatabase(){
        config = {
          name: '/sdcard/offline.db', // file:///sdcard/offline.db
          location: 'default'
        }
        this.sqlite.create(this.config).then(async  (db: SQLiteObject) => {
          await db.executeSql(`
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cond_pag (
              id_codizione_pag varchar(4),
              descrizione varchar(150),
              CONSTRAINT cond_pag_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_codizione_pag)  
           )`,{});

          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });    

      }
```